# Calculate variance of this law

Tags: probability, variance

> Consider $\mathcal{L}(X)=\frac{1}{n}\delta_0+(1-\frac{1}{n})\mu_N$, with $\mu_N=N(\frac{1}{n},1)$. Determine $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

My guess was:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\frac{1}{n}\int_\mathbb{R}x^2\cdot\delta_0(dx)+(1-\frac{1}{n})\int_\mathbb{R}x^2\cdot\mu_N(dx)=0+(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdot1$$
However, my answer file says that 
$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{1}{n^2})$
Could anyone point out where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Your error (and I recognize that I have done the same an hour ago) is that you have mixed a probability distribution with the sum of two random variables.

This type of probability law is called a mixture of two laws.

In order to understand it (and converge to the short solution given by @drhab), it helps to think to a simulation.

With the classical following functions (as implemented for example in Matlab):

- function rand, uniform on [0,1];
- function randn, normal with $m=0,\sigma=1$

this simulation would use an "if" in the following way:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{if rand} \  < \ \dfrac{1}{n}\\
 \ \ \ \  X=0\\
\text{else}\\
\ \ X=\dfrac{1}{n}+randn
\end{matrix}$$

If you have the habit to work with a software like Matlab, you may know that the expression (rand>1/n) has value 0 or 1 according to the fact that it is false or true (these 0 and 1 are the same time boolean values and numerial values). Thus, the simulation above can be simplified into:

$$X=\underbrace{(rand>\dfrac{1}{n})}_{B}\times\underbrace{(\dfrac{1}{n}+rand)}_N$$

...in full agreement with the product $X=BN$ @drhab has introduced, where $B$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$ (probability of success).

Comment: hmmm.. We are both upvoted, but one of us is wrong.

Comment: @drhab could you downvote my proof. I have not enough time to see where the flaw is. Thanks

Comment: You can delete it.

Comment: @drhab I have understood where was the flaw (confusion between the expression of a density and the expression of a random variable, shame on me), and  I realized that the Holograph had made the same mistake . This is why, I have written something that naturaly guides to the/your solution.

Comment: From downvote to upvote :).

Comment: @drhab : ...happy end...   :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realised that I accidentally confused $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\mathbb{V}[X]$, which of course, isn't true (in this case). Couldn't we, in general, just calculate the MGF of each term in the sum?

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ have [Bernouilli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with $\mathbb{P}\left(B=1\right)=1-\frac{1}{n}$
and let $N$ have a distribution such that its mean is $\frac{1}{n}$ and its 
variance is $1$. Note that $B^2=B$.

If $B$ and $N$ are defined on the same probability space and are independent then $X:=BN$ has the distribution
mentioned in your question.

We find:
$$\mathbb{E}X^{2}=\mathbb{E}B^{2}N^{2}=\mathbb{E}B^{2}\mathbb{E}N^{2}=\mathbb{P}\left(B=1\right)\mathbb{E}N^{2}=\mathbb{P}\left(B=1\right)\left[\text{Var}N+\left(\mathbb{E}N\right)^{2}\right]=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)$$